# Сбор вопросов для будущих кандидатов в модераторы сообщества 2019

Tags: обсуждение, выборы

В преддверии [выборов в модераторы сообщества за 2019 год](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/3), мы планируем провести сессию вопросов и ответов с кандидатами в модераторы. Сессия даёт возможность участникам сообщества задать интересующие их вопросы кандидатам. Участие полностью добровольное.

План таков.

- Ближайшую неделю любой участник может предложить свой вопрос к  кандидатам в модераторы ответом к этому вопросу. Пожалуйста, добавляйте *один вопрос к кандидатам в одном ответе*.
- Команда развития сообществ предоставит небольшой набор базовых вопросов. Первые *три* из них обязательно войдут в список вопросов кандидатам, Остальные попадут в него только в том случае, если сообщество не предложит достаточно интересных вопросов.
- Через неделю, команда развития сообществ выберет **до 7 вопросов от участников сообщества, набравших наибольшее количество голосов**. Эти вопросы будут использоваться в дополнение к трём вышеупомянутым обязательным вопросам. Команда развития сообществ оставляет за собой право вносить правки в вопросы так, чтобы они соответствовали выборам. В любом случае, если возникнут какие-либо замечания по содержанию вопросов, мы постараемся описать их в виде комментариев, дав автору возможность внести изменения.
- Как только сообщество определится с вопросами, будет создан новый вопрос, предназначенный для сбора ответов от кандидатов.
- Сессия вопросов и ответов — это прекрасная возможность понять, как кандидат смотрит на существующие в настоящий момент проблемы нашего сообщества. Хотите что–то узнать о будущем модераторе нашего сообщества? Добавьте ответ к этой публикации содержащий любой вопрос, который вы хотите задать кандидату.
- Кроме того, любой участник сообщества, может задать любой другой свой вопрос кандидатам или уточнить один из существующих в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).

Если у вас есть вопросы о процессе или вам есть чем его дополнить, пожалуйста, оставьте **комментарий к этому вопросу**.

---

**Обновление**

Вопросы больше не принимаются. Итоговый список вопросов: [Выборы модераторов сообщества 2019: ответы кандидатов на вопросы сообщества](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9115/6).

Comment: Сколько вакансий будет открыто?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ. две.

Answer (score 15):

Что вы думаете по поводу публичности решений модераторов? Вы согласны с тем, что не нужно разглашать такие вопросы публично или, всё же, считаете, что нужно их обсуждать вместе с сообществом на той же мете?

Comment: Я бы еще добавил - что вы будете делать, если обнаружите, что без публикации личной информации участников многие ваши решения выглядят в совершенно другом свете, а опубликовать вы ее не можете их-за ограничений мод соглашения :)

Comment: @PashaPash с согласия пользователя же можно. Не?

Comment: Нельзя даже с согласия пользователя. Это жесткий запрет. Пользователь всегда может сказать "май аккаунт воз хакед, это был не я". Или "я не думал, что вы так много информации раскроете". Или, в случае аккаунтов-клонов - просто заявит, что это все равно не он, вы раскрыли данные другого человека (соседа по комнате! да вместе живем, никогда и не скрывали, поэтому IP совпадает!). И напишет на компанию жалобу со штрафом. Поэтому любое раскрытие PII/ПД - это почти гарантированное снятие ромба.

Comment: @PashaPash допустим, вы удалили комментарий юзера (причина не важна), он просит его восстановить, т.к. там важная для него информация. Что здесь можно предпринять?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ достать из удаленного комментария информацию, отдать пользователю, и пусть что с ней хочет, то и делает?

Comment: @PashaPash Тут два момента: как отдать-то, через личный чат, например? А если он потом скажет, что его хакнули?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Я не совсем понимаю, причем удаление комментария к PII и модтулзам. Модераторам нельзя распространять PII. Если пользователь сам взял и опубликовал что-то в комментарии - модератор тут ни при чем.

Comment: @PashaPash вот я точно так же не понял, о какой личной информации речь шла в первом комментарии. Что такого личного может потребоваться опубликовать дабы не выглядеть "в совершенно другом свете"?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ок. например, вы, модератор, баните участника за ведение учеток-клонов. После этого он идет на мету, и утверждает, что вторая учетка не его, а забанили вы его из личной неприязни. Как вы предлагаете обсуждать и обосновывать такой бан на мете, если сам факт совпадения IP у двух участников - это личная информация? Более того, даже совпадение активности двух участников по времени, даже активность одного участника по времени - это pPII.

Comment: Как предполагается обсуждать, например, накрутку голосов? Получается, если на мете вам не удастся убедить людей, что участник голосовал сам за себя под левой учеткой - то в глазах сообщества вы автоматом становитесь нарушителем модсоглашения - ведь сообщество решило, что это два разных участника, а вы взяли и опубликовали их личные данные. Все, ромб долой, а участник подает на SO групповой иск.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ хуже того, в большинстве обсуждений с обоих сторон будут высказываться оценки поведения забаненного участника. Любая оценка, например "я считаю что он нарушил грубо и умышленно, достоин бана" автоматом позволяет участнику пойти на мету и обвинить вас, модератора, в преследовании его как личности. Т.к. он соглашался обсудить бан, но себя.

Comment: @PashaPash по-моему, вам нужно эти комментарии отдельным ответо-вопросом тут разместить. Авось и пройдет в топ для кандидатов.

Answer (score 14):

Предположим, что участники на мете с большим перевесом наголосовали за решение, с которым вы категорически несогласны (вырезание спасибо, запрет или разрешение домашней работы, запрет сарказма, you name it). Будете ли вы, как модератор, активно претворять его в жизнь, или постараетесь обойти соответствующие тревоги стороной?

Будете ли вы действовать иначе, если решение было принято не на локальной мете, а на английской MSE? А в случае, если решение принято не участниками, а администрацией сети SE?

Что вы будете делать, если обнаружите, что остальные модераторы обходят стороной соответствующие тревоги, и они начинают накапливаться?

Comment: Обалденный вопрос!

Answer (score 13):

Классический вопрос. Работать на благо сообщества вы можете и без статуса модератора. С вашей репутацией у вас уже и так доступны многие инструменты модератора. Так зачем вы действительно решили стать модератором?

Comment: Где-то я это уже слышал...

Comment: @αλεχολυτ каждый год задаю )

Comment: Ты тут столько вопросов назадавал, что голоса будут постоянно откатываться.

Comment: @Qwertiy 2019 год, а система выборов до сих пор работает через пень колоду (¬‿¬)

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, 3 или 4 плюса в день, 2 минуса.

Comment: @Qwertiy 3-4 модератора в неделю.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, ты их что, есть собрался что ли? Уже страшно ((

Answer (score 10):

Как, по-вашему, нужно ли вырезать из вопросов/комментариев приветствия и "спасибо"?

Answer (score 10):

Что вы думаете по поводу критики администрации и модераторов? Можно ли критиковать их решения и ошибки? Что если высказывание кажется ошибочным или даже ложным? Как отличить критику (возможно неумелую или недостаточно аргументированную) от клеветы? А если критика в основе своей объективна, но плохо сформулирована и может вызвать неоднозначную трактовку?

Answer (score 9):

Почему вы вообще сидите на SOru, если есть SOen? Считаете ли вы, что возможно, в принципе, создать полноценную базу знаний на русском, которая не будет уступать английской?

Answer (score 8):

В этом ответе вы можете найти набор базовых вопросов, призванных раскрыть как можно более общую информацию о кандидате. Как написано в инструкциях выше, первые три вопроса гарантированно появятся в итоговой сессии вопросов и ответов. Остальные — только в том случае, если сообщество опубликует недостаточно вопросов. Если вы считаете, что какой-то вопрос из списка, помимо трёх верхних, должен войти в итоговую сессию, пожалуйста, опубликуйте его в виде отдельного ответа.

- Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?
- Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?
- Важны ли для вас лично «[Нормы поведения](/conduct)», придерживаетесь ли вы их сами? Считаете ли вы нужным / важным дружелюбное отношение участников друг к другу? Как вы будете бороться с участниками, ведущими себя агрессивно?

---

- Что, по вашему мнению должен делать модератор?
- «Ромб» будет добавлен ко всему, что вы говорите и говорили в прошлом, включая вопросы, ответы и комментарии, а все, что вы сделаете в будущем, будет оценено под другим ракурсом. Что вы думаете по этому поводу?
- Каким образом статус модератора сделает ваши действия более эффективными в сравнении с ситуацией, когда вы просто наберете 10 или 20 тысяч баллов репутации?

Answer (score 8):

*Это — список идей для вопросов, которые надо задавать участникам. Конкретно эти вопросы из контекста не выдрать (они формируют единый рассказ), но я не буду против, если эти идеи разнесут по другим, независимым вопросам.*

*Все приведённые ниже вопросы — это сборная солянка из моего видения модераторства,
воспоминаний о некоторых драмах, попытки предвидеть развитие некоторых ситуаций,
да и просто предложений и предположений. Также сама формулировка вопросов направлена
на то, чтобы кандидат задумался о проблемах, подводных камнях и своей способности
с ними справиться.*

1. Сначала поговорим о ваших идеалах. Чем модератор в вашем представлении
   отличается от простого участника с высокой репутацией (>10K)?
2. Есть ли у вас самих высокая репутация?
3. Вы хоть знаете, как выглядят очереди на закрытие и переоткрытие?
4. Если не знаете: у модераторов очереди очень похожи, только их больше и вы будете
   судьёй Дреддом, а не одним из толпы голосующих, страхующей вопрос от вашей ошибки.

   1. Да, ошибки. Или вы готовы уничтожать небезнадёжные вопросы при дурном расположении
      духа или полной некомпетентности в предмете?
5. Если знаете: как часто вы там были? Каждый день? Раз в неделю? Где-то в районе
   первых трёх тысяч баллов репутации, когда вам эта очередь только что открылась?
   А как вы собираетесь разгребать модераторские очереди, которых больше и которые надо
   проверять ежедневно, а не по настроению?
6. А вы знали, что на Мете (https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com) тоже есть очереди тревог?
   Как давно вы туда заглядывали до прочтения этого вопроса?
7. Идём дальше. Основная задача модератора — окончательное устранение нарушений
   и улаживание конфликтов между участниками; для всего остального есть участники
   с высокой репутацией. Как вы это собираетесь делать?
8. Уточнение: банхаммером пользоваться запрещено. Подумайте ещё раз.
9. А если ситуация хоть и взрывоопасная, но по всем признакам скорее всего быстро
   перекипит и успокоится? Выждете спуска пара или рискнёте и заблокируете всех,
   переведя конфликт в вялотекущую или даже взорвущуюся в недалёком будущем фазу?
10. Вы не против вялотекущей фазы, потому что внешних проявлений конфликта вроде
    бы и нет? А что для вас важнее: общая соборность ресурса или довольные участники,
    которые от ущемлений сильно грустнеют? Почему?
11. А что, если никто не против конфликтной атмосферы, и единственное, что чувствует
    себя ущемлённым — правила ресурса?
12. А что, если к правилам добавится кто-то из других модераторов, но вы в целом не видите
    причин для оперативного вмешательства?
13. А что, если в *потенциально ущемлённых* окажутся понятия и категории людей, «особые» для
    США, но не имеющие абсолютно никакого негативного значения у нас (афроамериканцы
    или жители Латинской Америки, например)?
14. Нет, это реальный прецедент. Не забывайте, Stack Overflow — это международное
    сообщество с головным офисом в США. Вы готовы выучить американский культурный код
    и построить на его основе список запрещённых понятий, потому что этого никто ещё не сделал?
15. Более того, на жалобу может прийти участник из любого другого, англоязычного сообщества (см. полный список на http://stackexchange.com/sites).
    Вы готовы к общению с представителем чужой для вас культуры на чужом для вас языке?
16. А если этим представителем будет модератор того, другого сообщества?
17. Раскажите, где пролегает граница между «жалоба неправомерна, нужно объяснить
    пришедшему, что он неправ» и «атас, пора зачищать следы»?
18. Вы знали, что объяснять кому-то что-то через онлайн-переводчик — плохая затея,
    имеющая далёкие последствия из-за кривого перевода?
19. Использовать русский при общении с иностранцем тоже так себе затея. Здесь вам не
    https://russian.stackexchange.com.
20. Стандарт ресурса — не обидеть самого обидчивого. Как собираетесь разрешать
    возникающие из этого логические противоречия? Какие именно противоречия вы
    в этом видите?
21. Также модератор должен при возможности активно пресекать нарушения в зародыше,
    выявляя и устраняя причины зарождающихся конфликтов и «драм». Как вы собираетесь
    отслеживать веяния и настроения?
22. Часть участников сформировала своего рода сопротивление и общается на
    неприемлемые для администрации (и будущего вас в том числе) темы в стороннем чате.
    Темы эти зачастую неразрешимые из-за противоречия пользовательских ожиданий
    и политики компании. Будете ли вы представителем народа, аккуратно проводящим
    реформы, или будете блюсти незыблемость правил? Первое поднимет вашу репутацию
    в народе, но войдёт в коренное противоречие с вашими обязанностями и духом
    модераторства. Второе позволит спокойно заниматься прямыми обязанностями, но,
    возможно, осложнит вам жизнь в отдалённом будущем, когда на почве клубка
    противоречий вскроется очередная драма.
23. Модератор должен быть всегда на связи, чтобы не только отслеживать ситуацию,
    но и быть доступным для призыва. Как часто вы появляетесь в чате? Вы вообще знали,
    что у нас есть чат?
24. Вы помните, что помимо вас титул модератора имеют ещё несколько человек?
    Как будете кооперироваться? Как распределите обязанности? Вы вообще знаете
    ники участников, с которыми вам придётся сотрудничать?
25. Ещё, над всеми вами есть управляющий сообществом. Вы знаете, кто этот
    человек? С какими вопросами надо идти именно к нему, а с какими — на
    Метамету (https://meta.stackexchange.com)? Чем Метамета может быть полезна
    для модератора? Чем она лучше и хуже локальной меты (https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com)?
26. С точки зрения рядового пользователя модератор — это лицо и воплощение
    как администрации конкретного сайта, так и компании в целом. Вы готовы отказаться
    от своих убеждений и стать рупором политики компании? Что будете делать или стараться
    делать, если эта политика войдёт в конфликт с вашими убеждениями?
27. Ваши сообщения тоже станут частью вашего образа. Готовы ли вы перебрать все свои
    когда-либо опубликованные вопросы, ответы и комментарии, чтобы они были нейтральными как серый цвет при калибровке монитора?
28. Сколько вы сможете следить за нейтральностью и корректностью своей речи, чтобы
    она была для всех примером даже в самой накалённой обстановке? Через какое количество
    времени вы не выдержите такой стерильности и сложите с себя полномочия модератора?
29. Как планируете соблюдать нейтральность, не скатываясь при этом в безопасные и ни к чему не обязующие клише типа «ваш звонок очень важен для нас»?
30. Вы нашли неадекватного участника и расправились с ним. А он не расстроился
    и насоздавал ещё кучу учётных записей. Вы готовы долго, усердно и методично
    ходить за ним по пятам, выискивать новые следы его деятельности и отправлять
    очередного клона в Вальхаллу?
31. А если этот участник — ваш знакомый?
32. А если он в целом прекрасный специалист, активный отвечающий, талантище
    да и просто хороший человек, но у него есть пунктик, например, касательно идеи
    неполноценности авторов goto в C#?
33. А что, если этот участник знает вас в лицо, и как-то не хочется обижать
    хорошего человека?
34. Не существует способа понравиться всем. Обязательно найдутся недовольные
    вашей политикой, даже если она кажется вам или кому-то ещё правильной.
    Более того, у этих недовольных может оказаться активная учётная запись на
    таких популярных и достаточно авторитетных ресурсах, как Пикабу, Reddit или
    Хабрахабр. Что вы будете делать, если на одном из этих ресурсов появится
    желчный комментарий с критикой в ваш адрес?
35. А что, если это будет полноценный ненависти пост?
36. А что, если под критикой появится шквал единомышленников?
37. А что, если эту критику подхватят онлайн-издания, увидевшие в подобном инфоповод?
38. А что, если критика по делу?
39. Подождите, как вы определили, что критика была не по делу, а комментарии под ней —
    это «хайп за компанию»? И почему вы в этом уверены?
40. А если это вообще не конструктивная критика, а всего лишь словесный понос
    («винда — гавно», только вместо «винды» — вы)?
41. Наконец, поговорим о правилах. Знаете ли вы, что EULA, тур и справка — это далеко
    не единственные источники права на Stack Overflow?
42. Вы вообще читали хоть что-то из вышеперечисленного кроме тура?
43. Один из дополнительных источников права — это мета. Вы помните абсолютно все
    когда-либо опубликованные на ней прецеденты? Переберите все вопросы на ней, полезно для
    общего развития.
44. Я пошутил. Относительно недавно выяснилось, что мета — это ни разу не источник
    права. Обращайтесь после избрания к коллегам, они вам расскажут, на что именно
    надо ориентироваться. Ну и заодно пустят в секретный чат.

Удачи вам в летних выборах 2019 года, и чтобы ваши ожидания совпали с вашей новой реальностью модератора.

Comment: "Пожалуйста, добавляйте один вопрос к кандидатам в одном ответе" =/

Comment: @Suvitruf, это список идей для вопросов, которые надо задавать участникам. Конкретно эти вопросы из контекста не выдрать (они формируют единый рассказ), но я не буду против, если эти идеи разнесут по другим, независимым вопросам. Добавил это примечание в верхнюю часть сообщения.

Comment: @Arhad под вопросами вроде как подразумевались "вопросы, ответы на которые вы хотите услышать от кандидатов", а не "вопросы, на которые кандидат должен ответить, чтобы его допустили к выборам". Это ж не экзамен :)

Comment: @Arhad хотя, в качестве вопросов на подумать перед тем, как выдвигать кандидатуру - вполне ок

Comment: Я не понял, модераторы выбираются на РУ.стаковерфлоу или на всю площадку со 100500 сайтами?

Comment: @DaemonHK, на РУ. Но тревоги в любых чатах разлетаются по всей сети Stack Exchange. Учитывая наличие почти всего модсостава во [владельцах ру-комнаты](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/22462/stack-overflow--?tab=access), модерирование чата тоже, по факту, входит в обязанности модератора. Потому соответствующий пункт и попал в опросник выше.

Comment: @DaemonHK модераторы любого сайта сети могут модерировать этот конкретный сайт + весь chat.stackexchange.com. Т.е. в чате ruSO модераторы видят, например, тревоги в чате сайта, посвященному индуизму.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения) Бедные модеры...

Comment: @DaemonHK То, что модеры обязаны модерировать чат - лишь мнение Arhad. В официальных документах этого нет. Что касается тревог с религиозных сайтов, то на самом деле все пользователи с 10К+ репы "страдают" от этого. Ничего особенного для модеров нет.

Comment: А в этом сообщении есть что-то нехорошее. В моем ответе, возможно, тоже будет. Риторика типа *вы вообще хоть знаете, как делать X* на нейтральную не очень похожа. Говоря *Через какое количество времени вы не выдержите такой стерильности и сложите с себя полномочия модератора?* автор как бы утверждает что так и будет, хотя это вообще не факт. Можете перечислить тех модераторов, кто уже сложил с себя полномочия по этой причине? А насколько обосновано требование помнить *все* прецеденты с меты? Возможно ли такое вообще?

Comment: 22. Можно спокойно делать отдельным вопросом. 25. У модераторов есть больше мест. 27. Интересный вопрос, но спорный. Судя по всему, в дополнительных вопросах в ответе Николаса он на втором месте и та формулировка мне нравится больше.

Comment: 21. Тоже в отдельный вопрос. Давай сам задашь 21 и 22 чтобы слишком много моих вопросов не было? Я тут из твоих 2 вопроса сформировал, ещё хочу у Николаса утащить необязательный на голосование.

Comment: @Arhad, ау? Задашь 2 вопроса или всё-так мне придётся?

Comment: @Qwertiy мне пока некогда — предзащита диплома. Ну а насчёт количества вопросов, думаю, вообще волноваться не стоит (если обращать внимание на технические детали, то по этой логике Suvitruf вообще тогда должен вылететь из конкурса вопросов).

Comment: @Arhad, так просто скопипастить пункты ж целиком. Я как раз про технические - откат 4 плюсов подряд.

Comment: @Arhad, написал. Чуть не забыл про второй - там надо было минуту между ответами подождать, а мне через 45 вкладка попалась))

Answer (score 8):

Если вы будете не согласны с решением других модераторов по какому-либо вопросу, то вы будете стоять на своём или примете решение большинства модераторов?

Comment: И что делать в случае паритета? Бросать виртуальную монетку?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ звать независимого судью)

Comment: судья продажная (ц)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ как вариант - вынести обсуждение на мету

Answer (score 8):

Что думаете по поводу нынешнего положения меты? Активных пользователей можно по пальцам пересчитать. Мало кто читает мету в принципе, хотя происходят, порой, важные обсуждения. Нужно ли её как-то популяризировать?

Comment: Мне кажется, это скорее вообще вопрос к сообществу, а не к будущим модераторам. Не вижу почему модераторы могут больше сделать в плане популяризации.

Comment: @Qwertiy мне важно понять, что из себя представляет человек, который хочет стать модератором.

Answer (score 6):

Что, по-вашему, представляет собой "вредоносный шум"? И как с ним бороться (надо ли?!)?

Answer (score 6):

Чем для Вас является блокировка (бан) участника? В каких случаях, на Ваш взгляд, необходимо прибегать к этим мерам безоговорочно? Считаете ли Вы, что перед принятием такого решения этот вопрос необходимо вынести на обсуждение с сообществом? Или, на Ваш взгляд, это прерогатива сугубо модераторов?

Comment: Правилами сети регламентируется, что выносить бан на обсуждение сообществом нельзя. Информация о прошлых банах является приватной, а публичное обсуждение остаётся, поэтому его не должно быть. Да и само обсуждение привлечёт излишнее внимание.

Comment: @Qwertiy Правильно ли я понял, что если я получу бан, то его причина должна быть тайной за семью печатями?

Comment: Тебе причину сообщат. Ты можешь её сообщить кому-то ещё. Или кто-то может её и так знать, т. к. участвовал в истории. Но если модератор просто так возьмёт и потащит на мету обсуждение бана, то это какая-то жесть же.

Comment: @Qwertiy я в силу своей наивности думал, что обсуждение перед баном сможет отсеять некие спорные моменты... Думал о возможности некоего аналога народного суда, т.е. причина>голосование>бан... Скорее всего просто не выспался, вот и лезет в голову, как Вы выразились, жесть всякая...

Answer (score 6):

В комментариях под одним из вопросов/ответов разгорается конфликт участников, оба апеллируют к техническим деталям.

Вы не являетесь специалистом по метке обсуждаемого вопроса и не понимаете, кто из них прав. И других модераторов онлайн нету.

Какие действия вы предпримете в данной ситуации?

Answer (score 4):

Согласны ли вы с политикой администрации, что после получения ответа нужно удалять комментарии, т.к. они лишь "создают шум" и "отвлекают от вопроса"?

Comment: Очень странный вопрос. У нас нет такой политики. Есть политика "комментарии под вопросом - для уточнения вопроса, все остальное - должно быть ответом". Соответственно, ответы на уточняющие комментарии должны быть внесены в ответ, а не остаться висеть где-то в полотне переписки. А если они включены в ответ - то, обычно, нет смысла их держать еще и под вопросом.

Comment: @PashaPash Николас неоднократно повторял, что комментарии после получения ответа бесполезны и их бы вообще хорошо бы удалять. Или вы больше про то, что это его личная позиция, а не позиция компании?

Comment: Думаю, это было просто обобщенным утверждением. Очевидно, что некоторые (многие) комментарии стоит оставлять после получения ответа - как минимум, ссылки на связанные вопросы.

Answer (score 4):

- Как Вы поведёте себя, если вдруг, внезапно и негаданно, Ваша точка зрения разойдётся с точкой зрения КМ?
- Что Вы предпримете, если, по Вашему мнению, конечно, решение КМ носит несколько субъективный взгляд, основанный на личном видении ситуации, а не решение ситуации?

*Пример ситуации:*
Участник оскорбил КМ (Комьюнити-менеджера), который обиделся и забанил его.
Вы, модератор, свежим взглядом, увидели что тут есть случайная двусмысленность, которую не так поняли, либо излишне суровое наказание за то, что можно решить предупреждением.

Как Вы поступите в такой ситуации?
Будете ли Вы что-то делать для исправления ситуации?

**Помните:**

> Администратор (КМ) - не начальник модераторов, и не "вышестоящее
>   лицо".

Answer (score 4):

Будет ли у Вас иное отношение к участнику, у которого есть большой вклад в сообщество?
Поблажки или более суровое отношение, не суть.

Будет ли мнение такого участника важнее в, целом, равноценных прениях?

*Пример:*
Участник с 10000 ответов говорит что фича X не нужна.
Участник с 10 ответами говорит что фича X нужна.
Или же такие участники вообще не появляются в голосовании, т. к. не участвуют в опросе/не знаю о мете.

Будет ли решение основываться на мнениях (и, возможно, на количестве вклада высказывающегося) или на голых цифрах, которые можно нагнать просто толпой тех, кто жизнь сайте вообще не интересуется?

Comment: Пример какой-то странный. Вроде как на сайте нет споров о необходимости фич.

Comment: Ну вдруг возникнут?

Comment: Как это связано с модерированием? Модераторы никаких фич не делают.

Comment: @defaultlocale, Мнение модераторов по вопросам - ценно, поэтому как они будут думать - полезно знать.

Answer (score 4):

Что делать если ситуация хоть и взрывоопасная, но по всем признакам скорее всего быстро перекипит и успокоится? Выждете спуска пара или рискнёте и заблокируете всех, переведя конфликт в вялотекущую или даже взорвущуюся в недалёком будущем фазу? Как оценить потенциальные последствия каждого из этих вариантов?

<sub>На основе [поста](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/9054/revisions) от [@Arhad](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/208074/arhad).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Мнению участников, которые внесли действительно большой вклад в сообщество, вы уделите такое же внимание как и мнению рядовых участников?

Иными словами - если какое-либо мнение основных участников которые внесли б**о**льший вклад в сообщество отличается от мнения основного контингента(который почти не посещает мету/чат), что все нормально, вы прислушаетесь к мнению меньшинства?

Comment: Основной контингент своё мнение не высказывает. Мне кажется, этот вопрос о том же? https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9090/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy о том же. [Так получилось.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50302061#50302061) Мое [видение](https://freedom.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/122081-general/topic/.23SO.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.B2.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5/near/165735211) решения проблемы дублей - сделать тот вопрос общим и добавить в него информацию из моего вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

Будете ли вы сами применять какие-то действия к комментарию, если он показывался вам обидным, или только по тревоге? Скажем, один пользователь послал другого в гугл или написал неоднозначную фразу, которая потенциально **могла бы** обидеть. Если **вам** покажется, что она **может** обидеть собеседника, то удалите комментарий или только в случае появления тревоги на оном?

Comment: ... а может быть напишите ещё один подобный комментарий :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ провокатор (¬‿¬ )

Answer (score 1):

Можете ли Вы абстрагироваться от потенциальных выпадов в Ваш адрес и не смотря на них принимать расчётливые решения на пользу сообщества?

Comment: А ещё можно было бы спросить - "готовы ли вы честно отвечать на все вопросы?".

Answer (score 1):

«Ромб» будет добавлен ко всему, что вы говорите и говорили в прошлом, включая вопросы, ответы и комментарии, а все, что вы сделаете в будущем, будет оценено под другим ракурсом. Что вы думаете по этому поводу?

<sup>Вынес один из [необязательных вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9052/178988) на голосование.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Стандарт ресурса — не обидеть самого обидчивого. Как собираетесь разрешать возникающие из этого логические противоречия? Какие именно противоречия вы в этом видите?

Что для вас важнее: общая соборность ресурса или довольные участники, которые от ущемлений сильно грустнеют? Почему? А что, если единственное, что чувствует себя ущемлённым — правила ресурса?

Что, если в потенциально ущемлённых окажутся понятия и категории людей, «особые» для США, но не имеющие абсолютно никакого негативного значения у нас (афроамериканцы или жители Латинской Америки, например)? И что если это потом увидит представитель компании, имеющий американские культурные ценности?

<sub>На основе [поста](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/9054/revisions) от [@Arhad](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/208074/arhad).</sub>

Comment: «_Стандарт ресурса — не обидеть самого обидчивого_» — это несколько не так. На смежную тему есть ответ от [Jaydlas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231362/274323). В частности второй пункт, который говорит «Иногда, мы можем удалить содержимое, которое, вероятно, по настоящему обижает большую группу на вид разумных людей.»

Comment: "Потенциально ущемлённых окажутся понятия и категории людей, «особые» для США, но не имеющие абсолютно никакого негативного значения у нас" разве такое может быть в сегодняшнем невероятно связанном мире?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky да, и не только на SO, на том же dtf тоже свои драмы с неграми были.

Answer (score 0):

Также модератор должен при возможности активно пресекать нарушения в зародыше, выявляя и устраняя причины зарождающихся конфликтов и «драм». Как вы собираетесь отслеживать веяния и настроения?

<sub>Пункт 21 [поста](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/9054/revisions) от [@Arhad](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/208074/arhad).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Часть участников сформировала своего рода сопротивление и общается на неприемлемые для администрации (и будущего вас в том числе) темы в стороннем чате. Темы эти зачастую неразрешимые из-за противоречия пользовательских ожиданий и политики компании. Будете ли вы представителем народа, аккуратно проводящим реформы, или будете блюсти незыблемость правил? Первое поднимет вашу репутацию в народе, но войдёт в коренное противоречие с вашими обязанностями и духом модераторства. Второе позволит спокойно заниматься прямыми обязанностями, но, возможно, осложнит вам жизнь в отдалённом будущем, когда на почве клубка противоречий вскроется очередная драма.

<sub>Пункт 22 [поста](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/9054/revisions) от [@Arhad](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/208074/arhad).</sub>

Comment: Я конечно могу многое не понимать, но коим образом, сторонний чат относится к теме? Может быть удалить первые два предложения в вопросе?

Comment: @XelaNimed те, кто не в теме, понимают о чём речь )

Answer (score -1):

SO концептуально - это база знаний. Многие не раз поднимали тему, что таким образом вырезается/пропадает огромная доля общения. Предполагается, что SO - это не форум. Но раньше, как минимум, во времена хешкода, было больше общения и в более свободной форме. Что думаете на этот счёт? Действительно ли подход только лишь с накоплением знаний лучше?

Comment: Вопрос сформулирован так, что подразумевает определённый ответ) Может, его стоит скорректировать?

Comment: Также стоит убрать предпосылку о том что де SO был не базой знаний, а форумом - такое разве было?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб есть такое, подумаю над этим )

Comment: @Kromster форумом он никогда не был. Но раньше было по-другому всё же. Особенно во времена хешкода )

Comment: Вот про это вопрос и должен быть, вероятно. "раньше было по-другому всё же" ;-)

Comment: @Kromster лучше удалить вопрос вообще, думаю. Он к модераторству, в целом, мало чего общего имеет. Больше не нытьё старпёра похоже :D

Comment: Да нет, вопрос то в корне хорош, надо только найти его форму.

Comment: @Kromster попробовал по-другому. Что скажете?

Comment: "Раньше, во времена хэшкода, было лучше. А теперь о погоде".

Comment: Вопрос к кандидату должен быть *вопросом*. А не утверждением вашего личного мнения, о том, как было на хэшкоде :)

Comment: @PashaPash я поправил вопрос. Мне интересно мнение кандидата по поводу "базы знаний".

Comment: В нем все еще больше утверждения про то, что раньше было много общения, а сейчас вот исчезло. На самом деле мало кто помнит, как оно там было, на хэшкоде. Может и не было там общения, проверить же нельзя. Весь контент оттуда промигрирован - и что-то в старых вопросах не наблюдается теплоты и ламповости. Давайте не тянуть субъективные утверждения "сейчас не так свободно и общительно" в вопросы к кандидатам, ок?

Comment: @PashaPash так я не про свободы и т.п, а просто про мнение в плане "форумное общение vs база знаний".

Comment: Я понимаю, просто Хэшкод был клоном SO и точно так же был "базой знаний"/QA. Просто на нем, как и когда-то на SO, были разрешены дискуссионные вопросы. Форумом со свободным форматом он никогда не был.

Answer (score -1):

Как модератор вы будете выражать официальную позицию. Следовательно, к вашим словами пользователи будут относиться как к мнению администрации. Вы постараетесь меньше высказывать своё личное мнение (особенно по противоречивым темам) или "ваше мнение - это ваше мнение, и оно никак не связано с мнением администрации"?

Answer (score -4):

Считаете ли Вы себя стрессоустойчивым? Можете ли Вы выйти из себя?

Answer (score -6):

Что Вы будете делать, если отключат электричество и интернет?

Comment: Эм.. А модераторство тут каким боком?

Comment: Вы, лично Вы, читали первый пост? Цитата: Сессия даёт возможность участникам сообщества задать интересующие их вопросы кандидатам.