# Выборы модераторов сообщества 2019: ответы кандидатов на вопросы сообщества

Tags: обсуждение, выборы

Каждый участник, выдвигающийся на позицию модератора сообщества, имеет возможность поделиться своими мыслями с коллегами [по основным наболевшим вопросам](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9051/6) нашего сообщества. Ниже представлены семь вопросов от участников к вам, как кандидату, в дополнение к трём обязательными вопросам к рассмотрению.

### Ссылки на ответы кандидатов:

<sub>(В хронологическом порядке)</sub>

- [Suvitruf aka Андрей](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9116)
- [A K](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9131)
- [vp_arth](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9141)
- [doox911](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9160)
- [αλεχολυτ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9170)

### Инструкция: как отвечать на вопросы

1. Скопируйте шаблонный текст вопросов.
2. Вставьте его в новый ответ.
3. В начале поставьте своё имя и ссылку на профиль.
4. Пишите свои ответы после каждого блока цитаты и перед `---`, вот так:

   ```
   > Текст вопроса.

   Ваш ответ здесь.

   ---
   ```

### Памятка для кандидатов

- Ваша задача, как кандидата, крайне проста — опубликовать ваши мысли по всем обозначенным ниже вопросам одним ответом *на этот вопрос*.
- Пожалуйста, добавьте ваше имя (псевдоним на сайте) в самом начале ответа, чтобы другие участники понимали, чьи ответы они читают в данный момент.
- Пожалуйста, используйте форматирование как в этой публикации для выделения вопросов и ваших ответов к ним.

Как только все кандидаты разместят свои ответы, мы будем использовать данный вопрос как основу для принятия решений, чтобы каждый участник, который будет голосовать, понимал, почему он решил голосовать именно за данного кандидата.

#### Несколько слов о модераторах сообщества

Модератор сообщества – призвание, а не должность. Вам не обязательно быть «лучшим» специалистом среди коллег в определенной области (хотя разбираться в предмете все–таки стоит), чтобы быть модератором сообщества, но вам обязательно быть хорошим человеком, добрым, отзывчивым. На [Stack Overflow на русском мы в первую очередь ставим во главу угла наших коллег, уважение и доверительные отношения друг к другу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/key-values). И если ранее ваша «общественная репутация» в глазах коллег строилась на базе ваших знаний, вопросов и ответов, то после того, как вы станете модераторам, сообщество будет ценить вас за вашу добродетель не меньше, чем за профессиональные навыки.

Без модераторов крайне сложно создать по-настоящему дружное, интересное сообщество, а без сообщества, Stack Overflow – это просто набор битов на жёстком диске. Мы, люди, и есть Stack Overflow! Если вы верите в то, что можете менять мир вокруг себя к лучшему, добро пожаловать в нашу команду модераторов!

Желаю удачи, кандидаты!

> <sub>Тут же хотелось бы обратиться к сообществу, тем, кто будет отдавать свой голос за того или иного кандидата.</sub>
>
> <sub>Коллеги, пожалуйста, подойдите крайне ответственно к выбору модераторов! Модераторы — это фундамент сообщества. Они являются опорой для нас всех в первую очередь в случаях, когда что–то идет не так. Прежде чем отдать свой голос, подумайте, кого бы вы хотели увидеть в момент, когда с вами или с вашим коллегой на сайте произойдет что–то не так, когда вам понадобится помощь? Того кто спокоен, рассудителен, отзывчив, педантичен и добр? Или кого–то другого, например, кто знает больше анекдотов?</sub>
>
> <sub>Представьте, что вам нужно выбрать делового партнёра, которому вы бы смогли доверить ваше благополучие. Делайте ваш выбор исходя из того, что кандидат уже сделал для сообщества, а не обещает сделать, судите по общечеловеческим навыкам, а не знаниям программирования. В работе с людьми навыки программирования пригодятся мало.</sub>
>
> <sub>**От вашего выбора зависит будущее сообщества.**</sub>

### Вопросы

---

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создаёт большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

---

> Важны ли для вас лично «[Нормы поведения](/conduct)», придерживаетесь ли вы их сами? Считаете ли вы нужным / важным дружелюбное отношение участников друг к другу? Как вы будете бороться с участниками, ведущими себя агрессивно?

---

> Что вы будете делать, если обнаружите, что без публикации личной информации участников многие ваши решения выглядят в совершенно другом свете, а опубликовать вы её не можете из-за ограничений мод соглашения.

---

> Предположим, что участники на Mете с большим перевесом наголосовали за решение, с которым вы категорически несогласны (вырезание спасибо, запрет или разрешение домашней работы, запрет сарказма, you name it). Будете ли вы, как модератор, активно претворять его в жизнь, или постараетесь обойти соответствующие тревоги стороной?
>
> Будете ли вы действовать иначе, если решение было принято не на локальной мете, а на английской MSE? А в случае, если решение принято не участниками, а администрацией сети SE?
>
> Что вы будете делать, если обнаружите, что остальные модераторы обходят стороной соответствующие тревоги, и они начинают накапливаться?

---

> Работать на благо сообщества вы можете и без статуса модератора. С вашей репутацией у вас уже и так доступны многие инструменты модератора. Так зачем вы действительно решили стать модератором?

---

> В комментариях под одним из вопросов/ответов разгорается конфликт участников, оба апеллируют к техническим деталям.
>
> Вы не являетесь специалистом по метке обсуждаемого вопроса и не понимаете, кто из них прав. И других модераторов онлайн нету.
>
> Какие действия вы предпримете в данной ситуации?

---

> Назовите 4 главных качества, которыми, на ваш взгляд, должен обладать модератор Stack Overflow на русском.

---

> Чем для Вас является блокировка (бан) участника? В каких случаях, на Ваш взгляд, необходимо прибегать к этим мерам безоговорочно? Считаете ли Вы, что перед принятием такого решения этот вопрос необходимо вынести на обсуждение с сообществом? Или, на Ваш взгляд, это прерогатива сугубо модераторов?

---

> Что, по-вашему, представляет собой "вредоносный шум"? И как с ним бороться (надо ли?!)?

Comment: Так этап выдвижения еще не начался. Как-то странно этот пост создавать раньше времени.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ первые выборы же, процесс не отлажен   (¬‿¬ )

Comment: а почему раньше не проводились выборы на русском SO?

Comment: @naXa, это третьи выборы... все имеющиеся модераторы выбраны путём голосования

Comment: @naXa, вот ссылки на [первые выборы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/1) и [вторые выборы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/2)

Comment: @Suvitruf Интересно, вы говорите, что это первые выборы, но принимали участие во всех трёх.

Comment: @SKIP это была ирония, я частенько над такими вещами иронизирую. На SO многие баги не фиксятся годами )

Answer (score 29):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

## [Suvitruf aka Андрей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/15479/suvitruf)

---

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

Споры спорам рознь. Если нет переходов на личности и оскорблений, то это вполне приемлемо. У всех нас разный характер. Конечно, можно попытаться поговорить с человеком и указать, что можно быть помягче, но, моя практика показывает, что это может сделать только хуже. И это не зависит от уровня репутации пользователя.

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

Для начала обсужу с этим модератором. Если не получится разрулить ситуацию, то обсужу с остальными модераторами. А дальше решает большинство. Возможно, поинтересуюсь у сообщества, что оно думает на этот счёт.

---

> Важны ли для вас лично «[Нормы поведения](/conduct)», придерживаетесь ли вы их сами? Считаете ли вы нужным / важным дружелюбное отношение участников друг к другу? Как вы будете бороться с участниками, ведущими себя агрессивно?

Нормально себя вести и не оскорблять других очень важно для сообщества. Приторный CoC и насаждение be nice считаю плохой инициативой и мне не нравится, что всё это насаждается рьяно последнее время. Если под агрессивностью подразумеваются оскорбления, то:

1. На первый раз удаление комментариев и разговор с участников тет-а-тет.
2. При рецидивах, вероятно, бан.

Если речь про посылание в гугл, то за такое не банят. Максимум, можно намекнуть человеку, что лучше не посылать человека в гугл.

---

> Что вы будете делать, если обнаружите, что без публикации личной информации участников многие ваши решения выглядят в совершенно другом свете, а опубликовать вы её не можете из-за ограничений мод соглашения.

Я не понимаю, что подразумевается под "личной информацией", если честно. И не понимаю, каким образом это может повлиять на то, как решение выглядит со стороны. Если модератор без разглашения запрещённой информации не может донести решение, то это плохой модератор.

---

> Предположим, что участники на Mете с большим перевесом наголосовали за решение, с которым вы категорически несогласны (вырезание спасибо, запрет или разрешение домашней работы, запрет сарказма, you name it). Будете ли вы, как модератор, активно претворять его в жизнь, или постараетесь обойти соответствующие тревоги стороной?
>
> Будете ли вы действовать иначе, если решение было принято не на локальной мете, а на английской MSE? А в случае, если решение принято не участниками, а администрацией сети SE?
>
> Что вы будете делать, если обнаружите, что остальные модераторы обходят стороной соответствующие тревоги, и они начинают накапливаться?

Решение сообщества превыше всего. До той поры, пока это не противоречит правилам, естественно. Но тут стоит посмотреть ещё на голоса. Если было всего 5 проголосовавших, то такое обсуждение вряд ли можно считать волей сообщества.

У каждого подсайта сети свой менталитет, тем более, если речь о другом языке. Если какое-то решение не нравится нашему сообществу, то я буду прислушиваться к решению на нашей мете. Решение администрации, если оно не закреплено в правилах, а лишь на мете, ничем не отличается от решения сообщества. Так что, если сообщество примет решение противоположное решению администрации на MSE, то я буду следовать решению нашего сообщества.

Если модераторы обходят стороной тревоги, напишу им об этом, попутно сам разгребая эти тревоги.

---

> Работать на благо сообщества вы можете и без статуса модератора. С вашей репутацией у вас уже и так доступны многие инструменты модератора. Так зачем вы действительно решили стать модератором?

Модераторы к мнению других модераторов прислушиваются охотнее. Если я стану модератором, то появится реальная возможность донести мнение активной части сообщества до модераторов.

---

> В комментариях под одним из вопросов/ответов разгорается конфликт участников, оба апеллируют к техническим деталям.
>
> Вы не являетесь специалистом по метке обсуждаемого вопроса и не понимаете, кто из них прав. И других модераторов онлайн нету.
>
> Какие действия вы предпримете в данной ситуации?

Чатик с этими участниками, попрошу поумерить пыл. Если "конфликт" не нарушает правила, а просто являет собой жаркий спор, который относится к сути вопроса, то это вполне приемлемо, пока нет оскорблений и переходов на личности.

---

> Назовите 4 главных качества, которыми, на ваш взгляд, должен обладать модератор Stack Overflow на русском.

1. Критическое мышление. Не должен соглашаться с чьим-то решением только на основе авторитета. Должен взвесить все за и против, выслушать доводы всех сторон.
2. Не рубить с плеча (aka хладнокровие).
3. Ответственность за свои решение.
4. Осознание того, что все действия модератора теперь будут расцениваться как действия администрации.

---

> Чем для Вас является блокировка (бан) участника? В каких случаях, на Ваш взгляд, необходимо прибегать к этим мерам безоговорочно? Считаете ли Вы, что перед принятием такого решения этот вопрос необходимо вынести на обсуждение с сообществом? Или, на Ваш взгляд, это прерогатива сугубо модераторов?

Бан - это крайняя мера, когда слова уже не помогают. Если человек явно и намеренно нарушает правила после неоднократных предупреждений, то, не думаю, что стоит спрашивать сообщество. Примеры: расизм, оскорбления - довольно очевидные случаи. Если оскорбления/сарказм на грани, то есть смысл обсудить с сообществом, чтобы понять, как оно видит возможные варианты решения подобных ситуаций.

---

> Что, по-вашему, представляет собой "вредоносный шум"? И как с ним бороться (надо ли?!)?

Без понятия. Из тех обсуждений, что видел, никто не смог дать внятного и чёткого определения. А раз так, то и бороться с ним нет смысла. Скорее, без чёткого определения бороться даже вредно.

---

> Что вы думаете по поводу критики администрации и модераторов? Можно ли критиковать их решения и ошибки? Что если высказывание кажется ошибочным или даже ложным? Как отличить критику (возможно неумелую или недостаточно аргументированную) от клеветы? А если критика в основе своей объективна, но плохо сформулирована и может вызвать неоднозначную трактовку?

Если кто-то критикует действия/ошибки администрации, то нужно не удалять такие сообщения, а прислушиваться и попытаться исправить ситуацию. Если критикует не один участник, то в действиях явно что-то не так. Удалять такие сообщения равноценно собственноручному убийству сообщества.

---

> Часть участников сформировала своего рода сопротивление и общается на неприемлемые для администрации (и будущего вас в том числе) темы в стороннем чате. Темы эти зачастую неразрешимые из-за противоречия пользовательских ожиданий и политики компании. Будете ли вы представителем народа, аккуратно проводящим реформы, или будете блюсти незыблемость правил? Первое поднимет вашу репутацию в народе, но войдёт в коренное противоречие с вашими обязанностями и духом модераторства. Второе позволит спокойно заниматься прямыми обязанностями, но, возможно, осложнит вам жизнь в отдалённом будущем, когда на почве клубка противоречий вскроется очередная драма.

Как участник альтернативного чата могу сказать, что большая часть обсуждений не нарушают правил. Одна из моих целей как раз стать звеном между расколотыми частями нашего сообщества.

Comment: Вы мой герой!!!

Comment: Все  ответы очень хороши. По поводу большинства: в данном случаи имеем дело с грамотными людьми,  поэтому большинство  должно решать, но, обычно, я считаю, что мнение большинства какраз и является ошибочным, потому что в мире большинство неправильно все понимают или вообше ничего не понимают...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Вам бы в политики: `большинство должно решать`, далее `обычно, я считаю, что мнение большинства ... является ошибочным`, и под занавес `в мире большинство ... вообще ничего не понимают`.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan мы это не раз обсуждали на мете и в чате. Нет однозначности в этом вопросе)

Comment: А если всё-таки проблема "вредоносного шума" существует и она не придумана? У нас могут некоторые участники месяцами могли оккупировать чат на какую-то демагогию с неприятными ярлыками, совершенно не слыша собеседников и будучи очень навязчивыми. Неужели подобное поведение должно оставаться безнаказанным так долго?

Comment: `Если оскорбления/сарказм на грани, то есть смысл обсудить с сообществом` — а это зачем? Недостаточно ли просто пояснить начавшему это, что так нельзя и если не последовало понимания, то в бан.

Comment: `А если всё-таки проблема "вредоносного шума" существует и она не придумана` если она есть, то нужны пруфы и обсуждение на мете, а не просто баны. Даже если бан был правомерен, со стороны многим может показаться предвзятость модератора.

Comment: `а это зачем?` - а почему нельзя то? "на грани" на то и на грани, что разными пользователями может трактоваться по-разному.

Comment: @Suvitruf Я тогда вообще не понимаю вашу мысль про "на грани". Вам прилетает тревога на комментарий или пост. Как вы поймёте, что это "на грани"? В каких случаях надо "обсудить с сообществом" и как это вообще выглядит?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov опять же, от ситуации зависит. Скорей всего, всё же, если тревога была, то придётся удалить, если намёк на нарушение был. "Обсудить" подразумевает обсуждение обобщённого случая. Скажем, если в комментарии был сарказм, на него поставили тревогу -> я бы предложил обсуждение на мете по поводу сарказма (что, в общем-то, в своё время мы и наблюдали). Обсуждение подразумевает обобщённый случай, а не конкретный, если что.

Comment: Удивитильная способность на некоторые вопросы написать ответ, но на вопрос не ответить. Пример - самый первый вопрос :-)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko вопросов много, как мог ответил. А править постфактум уже не видел смысла, т.к. часть людей уже проголосовало и было бы не совсем честно по отношению к ним.

Comment: Можно не править, а дополнить. После дополнения, участники могут изменить свое мнение и это нормально. А вопросов действительно много.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko буду дома, подумаю над вопросами ещё разок.

Comment: Не могли бы Вы как-то подробнее рассказать что именно Вы собираетесь делать чтобы стать «звеном между расколотыми частями нашего сообщества» и как Вам в этом поможет бубен? Просто пока Ваша основная причина для участия в выборах как-то слабо освещена.

Comment: @defaultlocale потому что я общаюсь с обеими сторонами. А текущий мод. состав вообще игнорирует так называемое "сопротивление". Чем поможет ромб? Тем, что модераторы будут вынуждены меня, как минимум, выслушивать. Т.е, задача минимум - донести до них идеи/проблемы.

Comment: @Suvitruf Вот как разно интересно было бы посмотреть на конкретные идеи/проблемы о которых Вы будете говорить. Например я в альтчат не хожу и не в курсе чего добиваются подпольщики, думаю я не один такой. Полагаю что пары пунктов было бы достаточно чтобы составить представление.

Comment: @defaultlocale как пример, КМ часто говорил, что `незаменимых нет`. Модераторы, как мне кажется, часто путают критику с клеветой. Так же, от них часто звучит тезис, что `активные участники - это не всё сообщество` и `решения на мете ничего не значат, т.к. приняты меньшинством`. Это прям сходу. Так-то проблемных тем много. На мете даже тема про это есть (и не одна).

Comment: @Suvitruf как вы относитесь к пассивной агрессии? Когда нет перехода на личности, но над человеком косвенно насмехаются, провоцируя его на оскорбительный комментарий? Например пишут о том, что вопрос странный и не реальный, настойчиво спрашивают зачем вообще нужно делать именно так, в комментариях к вопросу, говорят о том, что вопрос глупый, без объяснения причин и подобные приёмы.

Comment: @Петр я вообще не против иронии/сарказма, но в комментариях частенько люди перебарщивают. Многие просто уже забыли, что когда-то сами были новичками и задавали простые (или даже глупые) вопросы. Насмешки - это плохо. В лёгкой иронии не вижу проблемы. `настойчиво спрашивают зачем вообще нужно делать именно так` потому что авторы вопросы знают, чего хотят, но не редко забывают, что отвечающие-то контекста не знают. Думаю, по большей части, все эти уточнения в комментариях вызваны тем, что люди не понимают, как ответить однозначно на вопрос. Если же в комментариях видите оскорбления, то флагайте.

Answer (score 23):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[A K](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/213987/a-k)

---

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создаёт большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

Я считаю участников сайта одной из самых больших ценностей нашего ресурса, а дружелюбную атмосферу на сайте — ценностью ещё более высокого порядка. В описываемом случае речь идёт о неоднократных нарушениях, когда нарушителя следует забанить: как бы мне не было прискорбно, но бан является жесткой, но необходимой мерой.

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

Я [отвечал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6072/) ранее на этот вопрос, моя позиция не поменялась и мне нечего добавить к сказанному два года назад.

---

> Важны ли для вас лично «[Нормы поведения](/conduct)», придерживаетесь ли вы их сами? Считаете ли вы нужным / важным дружелюбное отношение участников друг к другу? Как вы будете бороться с участниками, ведущими себя агрессивно?

Мои личные ценности формировались задолго до времен, когда никаких норм поведения не было на сайте, да и интернета ещё не было. И в общем-то они вполне совпадают с теми нормами и ценностями, которые описаны на stackoverflow — и то и то это вполне типичный набор европейских либеральных ценностей. Придерживаюсь ли я их? Да, вполне. При этом это происходит не через силу, а "на автопилоте", в силу привычки. (Кто-то меня спрашивал, почему я всё время "на вы" обращаюсь: а вот это оттуда же идёт) Бывают и эксцессы (все мы люди), но мне кажется что не часто.

> Как вы будете бороться с участниками, ведущими себя агрессивно?

Агрессия в открытом виде не так часто встречается у нас на сайте, я считаю гораздо более серьёзной проблемой скрытую агрессию, высокомерное отношение и другие менее заметные вещи. С открытой агрессией бороться намного проще, с остальным я знаю только один способ, он небыстрый и сложный: личный пример.

---

> Что вы будете делать, если обнаружите, что без публикации личной информации участников многие ваши решения выглядят в совершенно другом свете, а опубликовать вы её не можете из-за ограничений мод соглашения.

За последний год я лично наблюдал несколько подобных случаев, поэтому иллюзий по этому поводу я не испытываю. (Очень хорошо по этому поводу [сказал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5987/213987) когда-то Nofate)

Могу сказать, что приоритет правил сайта (мод. соглашения) для меня очевиден в этом случае. Модератор не должен думать о том, в каком свете видят его участники, ориентироваться на популярность. Поступай как должно, надейся, что люди за твоими поступками смогут разглядеть твои ценности.

---

> Предположим, что участники на Mете с большим перевесом наголосовали за решение, с которым вы категорически несогласны (вырезание спасибо, запрет или разрешение домашней работы, запрет сарказма, you name it). Будете ли вы, как модератор, активно претворять его в жизнь, или постараетесь обойти соответствующие тревоги стороной?

Этот вопрос очень важен для меня лично. На мете есть множество обсуждений на основании которых были приняты решения, которые мне нравятся, были и те, которые с которыми я не согласен. Думаю, что каждый из нас сталкивался с подобным. Лично я придерживаюсь следующего подхода: правило может тебе не нравиться, но это не является основанием для того, чтобы его не соблюдать.

Я однозначно буду пытаться повлиять на то, чтобы не было принято правило, которое я считаю неправильным или ошибочным; если я увижу более хороший вариант, чем мой — я согласен его продвигать как собственный. И я точно не считаю, что став модератором я перестану быть активным участником сайта, чтобы никак не поколебать общественный консенсус. (Не будем преувеличивать роль ромба: это всего лишь один голос при голосовании, остальные добываются острым умом, подвешенным языком и аргументацией. Авторитет лычек... вот не видел я, чтобы у нас на это велись: у нас смотрят на дела, а не на регалии) Я очень хорошо помню случай, когда модератор [продвигал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6189/213987) свою точку зрения, потому что считал её правильной и считаю, что участник-модератор остаётся участником и до принятия итогов может высказываться и агитировать за те вещи, которые он считает правильными. После принятия решения - и модератор и участник должны правило соблюдать.

> Будете ли вы действовать иначе, если решение было принято не на локальной мете, а на английской MSE? А в случае, если решение принято не участниками, а администрацией сети SE?

Да это как-то это и не играет роль, где решение принято. Правила с MSE постепенно расходятся по локальным сайтам и их метам, администрация обычно правила выравнивает по всей сети.

Надо сказать, что правила формулируются исходя из ценностей, которые сами по себе являются ценностями высокими, гуманистическими, так что проблем следовать им нет.

Я помню случаи, когда правила были недостаточно разъяснены, поэтому на основе недопонимания рождались разного рода опасения. Ну, я и раньше как участник в стороне не стоял и сейчас не собираюсь.

> Что вы будете делать, если обнаружите, что остальные модераторы обходят стороной соответствующие тревоги, и они начинают накапливаться?

Я не знаю для себя общего ответа на этот вопрос. Я вполне могу представить и ситуации, в которых буду забирать подобные вопросы на себя (если остальные будут обходить); могу представить, что до момента, пока это не станет проблемой буду аккуратно обходить такие вопросы стороной и думать, что с этим могу сделать. Могу точно сказать, что в случае если начнётся обсуждение проблемы по существу — замалчивать не буду и постараюсь найти приемлемое решение. Не исключаю, что в каком-то предельном случае правильным будет провести довыборы модераторов или даже перевыборы. Готов ли я положить в таком случае  партбилет на стол? Готов.

---

> Работать на благо сообщества вы можете и без статуса модератора. С вашей репутацией у вас уже и так доступны многие инструменты модератора. Так зачем вы действительно решили стать модератором?

На прошлых выборах я говорил, что мне здесь нравится (а когда нравится — хочется, чтобы любимое место становилось лучше). Я по-прежнему могу подписаться под каждым этим словом, потому что чувствую так.
Но есть и ещё, что поменялось с тех пор. Я вижу достаточно серьёзный кризис в сообществе, который тянется уже более года.
По мере возможности я старался помочь в его разрешении, иногда удачно... иногда так себе. Может быть я ошибаюсь, но мне кажется что находясь внутри модсостава имеешь больше возможностей для коммуникации в обе стороны.

---

> В комментариях под одним из вопросов/ответов разгорается конфликт участников, оба апеллируют к техническим деталям.
>
> Вы не являетесь специалистом по метке обсуждаемого вопроса и не понимаете, кто из них прав. И других модераторов онлайн нету.
>
> Какие действия вы предпримете в данной ситуации?

Я был автором этого вопроса и мне как участнику сайта было интересно посмотреть, кто из кандидатов какие вопросы здесь вообще видит, тут сразу несколько ситуаций:

- считаете, что можно не будучи экспертом рассудить других экспертов? (да — считаю; да — важно просить соблюсти уважительный характер беседы и это уже большая помощь; да — неплохо бы представлять пределы своей компетенции и когда стоит прекратить выезжать на интуиции)
- о разделении ответственности с другими участниками и умении взять ответственность на себя, когда это необходимо (коллегиальное действительно предпочтительнее; иногда приходится быть "боевой единицей сам в себе")

Мммм... А можно я не все опишу, что вижу? ;) Хочу всё-таки посмотреть ответы других.

---

> Назовите 4 главных качества, которыми, на ваш взгляд, должен обладать модератор Stack Overflow на русском.

Главное качество модератора должно быть — уважительное отношение к человеку. Я хотел бы модераторов, которые бы поступали по букве закона, но при этом исходили бы из гуманистических позиций. Прямо говоря, можно легко поступить по букве закона, но при этом увеличить количество негатива.

Второе это ответственность. Модераторам даются достаточно мощные инструменты, чем мощнее инструмент — тем больше должна быть и ответственность при их применении.

Как по мне — это ключевые качества. Я видел вполне успешных модераторов, кто был молчуном и видел с хорошо подвешенным языком, молодых и взрослых, всяких. На мой взгляд это всё уже подпадает под индивидуальные особенности, у каждого они свои.

---

> Чем для Вас является блокировка (бан) участника? В каких случаях, на Ваш взгляд, необходимо прибегать к этим мерам безоговорочно? Считаете ли Вы, что перед принятием такого решения этот вопрос необходимо вынести на обсуждение с сообществом? Или, на Ваш взгляд, это прерогатива сугубо модераторов?

Если бан применяется ко мне, то бан для меня — это шок, гнев и прочий букет эмоций. Если банхаммер в моих руках — то бан для меня это весьма неприятное действие, я бы предпочёл без него обойтись. Если отстраниться от личного аспекта, то бан — это одна из крайних мер силового воздействия на нарушителей. Безоговорочный бан я вижу только в случае неоднократных грубых нарушений (ну, типа оскорбления участников), когда другие меры не помогают.

Оставшаяся часть вопроса — о коллегиальности решения (коллегиальные решения лучше) и о публичности решений модераторов. Вообще, я считаю открытость и прозрачность действий модераторов очень полезным и в этом плане я поддерживаю инициативы @VladD, вполне возможно что со временем политика управляющей компании станет более либеральной.

---

> Что, по-вашему, представляет собой "вредоносный шум"? И как с ним бороться (надо ли?!)?

В исходном значении под этим понималось всё, что отвлекает участников от основной цели сайта (пополнение базы знаний), ну там разный оффтопик под вопросами, приветы, спасибы и проч. Типа, прямая дорога цель -> ответ без всяких комментариев и отвлечений. Я не вижу в этом ничего плохого, у so очень узкий формат и лёгкий оживляж в разумных рамках только в плюс.

А если вопрос не про вредоносный шум, а про "вредоносный шум" — то это синоним для слова "неконструктивная критика". Я  считаю, что из критики нужно стараться выжать здравое зерно и обращать на пользу сайта, а бороться с ней не надо.

> Что вы думаете по поводу критики администрации и модераторов? Можно ли критиковать их решения и ошибки? Что если высказывание кажется ошибочным или даже ложным? Как отличить критику (возможно неумелую или недостаточно аргументированную) от клеветы? А если критика в основе своей объективна, но плохо сформулирована и может вызвать неоднозначную трактовку?

Критика — полезна, так как двигает сообщество вперёд, позволяет увидеть какие-то вещи, которые сам не замечаешь. Если высказывание кажется ошибочным или ложным - нужно а) сказать об этом, б) послушать обратную связь. Это в большинстве случаев хорошо помогает убрать случайные недопонимания, неточные формулировки, неумение чётко выражать свои мысли.

Насчёт критериев клеветы я тогда много думал, но если не считать того, что надо отделять переходы на личности могу сказать только следующее. Надо смотреть на то, как человек относится к фактам, которые он получает от других лиц (невозможно везде успеть, некоторые вещи можно только от других узнать): если видны признаки критического мышления ("верно ли я слышал, что", "по словам такого-то", "как вы считаете" и т.п.) то вероятно перед нами попытка разобраться в вопросе и налицо конструктив; если человек проявляет эмоциональность - то это опасная дорожка, которая может привести к неконструктивной критике и взаимным оскорблениям.

### Ответы на дополнительные вопросы участников

---

> Часть участников сформировала своего рода сопротивление и общается на неприемлемые для администрации (и будущего вас в том числе) темы в стороннем чате. Темы эти зачастую неразрешимые из-за противоречия пользовательских ожиданий и политики компании. Будете ли вы представителем народа, аккуратно проводящим реформы, или будете блюсти незыблемость правил? Первое поднимет вашу репутацию в народе, но войдёт в коренное противоречие с вашими обязанностями и духом модераторства. Второе позволит спокойно заниматься прямыми обязанностями, но, возможно, осложнит вам жизнь в отдалённом будущем, когда на почве клубка противоречий вскроется очередная драма.

Не помню кто сказал, что в современном мире герои мифов стали невозможными: мы слишком много про них знаем, чтобы очаровываться ими. С этой точки зрения мне кажется архаичной и потому смешной идея цензуры: всегда можно уйти в любое другое место, запретить кому-то общаться только тут и больше нигде глупо. Уход людей - признак того, что им что-то не нравится, в этом плане лучшее что можно сделать - не держать силком, а радоваться когда ваши цели совпадают и они снова заходят к тебе.

За тем чатом давно не слежу, но когда-то туда ушло много весьма достойных людей, которых хорошо знаю по ru so и у меня о них сложилось хорошее мнение. Многое из того, что тогда говорилось и стало причиной их ухода я поддерживаю и одобряю. В той мере в которой разделяю эти цели постараюсь поспособствовать и дело не в репутации, а в том, что это и мои цели. Будучи же реалистом я уже достаточно хорошо понял возможные ограничения (темы реально упираются в невозможное), поэтому понимаю, что задача вполне возможно не будет решена в ближайшее время и кому-то придётся продолжить это дело.

> Как вы считаете, нужно ли банить за ссылки на сайты, на которых не
> приняты такие же правила, как и на SO, и которые не нарушают ни
> американский, ни российский закон (например, на Гугл или
> альтернативный чат)?

1. Отправка в поисковики [не рекомендуется](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2013/213987)
2. В вопросах и ответах лучше приводить самое существенное из материала по ссылке, в противном случае вероятно удаление по причине "вопрос-ссылка"
3. Нетематические cсылки под вопросами/ответами могут быть удалены по тревоге, как не относящийся к данному сообщению.
4. В остальном информация для меня есть просто информация, неважно где она размещена: на вики, тостере, каких-то альтернативных сайтах.
5. Вот разве сайты с автопереводами меня лично бесят, но причин для бана тут нет: можно молча поменять ссылку и рекомендовать участнику в комментариях ссылаться на оригинальные вопросы на en so, а не на сайты-прокладки. Но я за последние полгода не помню, чтобы такие ссылки попадались: видно не только мне одному эти сайты кажутся однодневками, не стоящими внимания.

Comment: Со скрытой агрессией можно бороться провокацией на открытую))

Comment: @yolosora провокация на агрессию и есть скрытая агрессия

Comment: Про ссылки. А если речь про чат? Из чата, к примеру, на альт чат ссылки выпиливались, а участники банились.

Comment: @Suvitruf А для чего ссылки на некий "альт чат" приводились? И почему продвижение других платформ должно считаться нормой?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov вопрос в том, почему ссылки на сайт, не запрещённый правилами, вырезаются.

Comment: @Suvitruf Да вот хотя бы потому что это реклама какой-то платформы, где как я понимаю, обсуждаются участники данного сайта в дурном свете. Почему подобное должно быть разрешено?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov 1) про "обсуждаются участники данного сайта в дурном свете" - это выдумки. 2) ссылки в ответах - это тоже реклама? А ссылки на habr? Пользователи ушли на альт платформу не от хорошей жизни.

Comment: @Suvitruf Почему вы мыслите в категориях, что должна быть причина удалять контент? На мой взгляд ценность данного сайта в том, чтобы была причина оставить. А есть нет, то контенту не место здесь. Какая причина оставлять ссылки на всякие "протестные" платформы?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov почему вы называете её "протестной"?

Comment: @Suvitruf А это я придумал названия SOпротивление, SOмнения и может что-то ещё, я не следил? Ну неважно, это лирика. Замените на "альтернативную" и ответьте на сам вопрос, пожалуйста: для чего оставлять ссылки?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov почему нет? Я сейчас про чат и мету, если что.

Comment: Почему нет, я рассказал выше, не хочу повторяться. На вопрос "почему да?" я так понимаю не будет нормального ответа?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov я за удаление только того, что идёт в разрез с правилами и того, что мешает. Вы как будто белые списки создать хотите.

Comment: Можно вопрос? Как вы поступите с новым участником, который не прочел справку или тур, и задал некачественный вопрос?

Comment: @VerNick Таких много приходит. Людям как правило нужна быстрая помощь, но многие готовы и инвестировать время чтобы выиграть на более долгую дистанцию. Некачественный вопрос можно закрыть (если уж совсем не исправить), судить же человека по одному поступку недальновидно. Я не всегда даю ссылку на правила, но стараюсь, чтобы перед голосом за закрытие оставить комментарий, в котором пояснить что  не так.

Comment: @AK Хорошо, спасибо.

Answer (score 20):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### [αλεχολυτ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B5%CF%87%CE%BF%CE%BB%CF%85%CF%84)

---

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создаёт большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

У меня на примете есть, как минимум, два участника, которые могли бы быть прототипами для создания подобного вопроса. Оба на текущий момент находятся в бане. Но несмотря на попадания обоих в бан, причины всё же были разные (насколько я могу судить по тем данным, которые мне доступны). Когда мы говорим, что участник создал много ценных ответов, мы подразумеваем, что это произошло всё же не одномоментно, а это значит, что либо раньше тревожных споров под ответами не было, или же они были, но действующие модераторы как-то разруливали ситуацию, не способствуя уходу участника с сайта. В случае постоянных (и действительно актуальных) тревог "чаша терпения" модераторов переполняется и участник попадает в бан. Решение об этом, как мне видится, должно приниматься коллегиально - нельзя просто так разбрасываться банами, тем более в сторону участников, формирующих полезный контент серьёзного объёма. Однако, всему есть предел, да и баны, насколько я знаю, имеют кумулятивный эффект (каждый последующий бан даётся на больший срок). Стабильная и размеренная жизнь сайта важнее постоянных выяснений отношений и склок. Этот случай можно отнести к соответствующему типу характера участника - что-то вроде бунтарь-интеллектуал. Такого участника вряд ли что-то сможет исправить. Другое дело, когда продолжительно время участник генерил контент и всё было хорошо, но потом что-то изменилось и пошли те самые тревоги в комментариях. И вот здесь надо разбираться, а что же действительно произошло с участником. Нужен диалог (не могу пока знать, как его правильнее организовать средствами SE - модераторские сообщения, или приватный чат, может быть вовсе переписка по почте), чтобы найти корень проблемы. В целом адекватный человек должен быть способен на проведение такого диалога (участник - модераторы). В любом случае, бан - это крайняя мера, которую стоит применять к участнику. Ну и так же, я бы не стал забывать о тех, кто пострадал (или мог пострадать) от действий этого участника, до них тоже стоило бы каким-то образом донести результаты разборки ситуации. Кому-то может быть достаточным увидеть, что его флаг был признан полезным, а кому-то надо несколько шире раскрыть решение мод.состава.

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

Я предпочитаю действовать быстро, вижу проблему - пишу об этом. Решение, при этом, не всегда успевает в срок (по моему мнению). Т.о. если модератор онлайн - задам ему соответствующий уточняющий вопрос, попробуем обсудить ситуацию, может кто-то из нас чего-то не понял. Если к консенсусу придти не удалось, лучше всё оставить как есть, т.е. не производить каких-то откатов, восстановлений и т.д., чтобы не создавать ситуацию вида "войны правок". Раздор среди мод.состава будет выглядеть очень плачевно со стороны. Стоит подождать других модераторов и принять более взвешенное решение, что делать дальше.

---

> Важны ли для вас лично «[Нормы поведения](/conduct)», придерживаетесь ли вы их сами? Считаете ли вы нужным / важным дружелюбное отношение участников друг к другу? Как вы будете бороться с участниками, ведущими себя агрессивно?

Нормы важны. Однако, там же есть такая фраза "письменная речь плохо передаёт тон высказываний", и это можно отнести к чему угодно. Кто-то был в плохом настроении, когда прочитал совершенно безобидную фразу; кто-то не уловил контекст; кто-то пришёл из "другого мира" и смотрит на всё несколько иначе, чем есть на самом деле. Я считаю, что здравомыслящему человеку никакие писанные "Нормы" не нужны, он автоматически следует им изо дня в день. Не нужно сообщать человеку, что оскорблять других - это плохо, это должно быть уже на подсознании. Жалко при этом, что всё же культурные границы западного мира и русского хоть и пересекаются, но всё же не совпадают, а сайты SE, это всё же иностранный продукт, который требует и вполне себе имеет на это право, определённого поведения. Но всё же хорошо, что модераторами являются в первую очередь люди русского мировоззрения, нежели западного. Если, скажем, модераторов бы назначали из заокеанского офиса компании (пусть даже это будут люди, знающие русский язык), а не выбирались участниками, было бы намного хуже. Поэтому CoC CoC'ом, но я думаю, на этом сайте мы сами себе хозяева и никто не сможет обвинить нас в расизме за фразы типа "как белый человек", как это могло бы быть сделано на других (англоязычных) сайтах SE.

---

> Что вы будете делать, если обнаружите, что без публикации личной информации участников многие ваши решения выглядят в совершенно другом свете, а опубликовать вы её не можете из-за ограничений мод соглашения.

Я вот пытался выяснить, что же это за гипотетические ситуации такие могут быть и получил [комментарий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9051/%D0%A1%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-2019/9057#comment37537_9057) от действующего модератора. Всё это выглядит довольно странным, неясно, почему, скажем указание того, что UserA есть клон UserB является раскрытием личной информации, а факт объединения учёток (который будет по итогам виден всем, т.к. ссылки станут вести на один профиль) не относится к таковому. В общем, такого рода тонкости предстоит ещё обсудить и вероятно на более высоком уровне, нежели ruSO Meta, но в целом проблема мне кажется раздутой, а модераторы запуганными потерей ромба. Рассчитываю, что будучи выбран, я смогу лучше разобраться в этой ситуации и, надеюсь, смогу опубликовать пост, раскрывающий этот момент более подробно (без публикации личной информации, конечно:)

---

> Предположим, что участники на Mете с большим перевесом наголосовали за решение, с которым вы категорически несогласны (вырезание спасибо, запрет или разрешение домашней работы, запрет сарказма, you name it). Будете ли вы, как модератор, активно претворять его в жизнь, или постараетесь обойти соответствующие тревоги стороной?
>
> Будете ли вы действовать иначе, если решение было принято не на локальной мете, а на английской MSE? А в случае, если решение принято не участниками, а администрацией сети SE?
>
> Что вы будете делать, если обнаружите, что остальные модераторы обходят стороной соответствующие тревоги, и они начинают накапливаться?

Вряд ли я буду активно претворять в жизнь решения, с которыми не согласен. Другое дело, что в случае принятия разумным большинством, я также не буду и противиться этим решениям. Это как корпоративный Code Style, ему надо следовать даже в тех моментах, с которыми несогласен, если плюсы нахождения в компании перевешивают минусы. По моим наблюдениям, именно обход стороной некоторых неочевидных моментов является приоритетным вариантом у действующих модераторов. Но кто их знает, что они там обсуждают в своём секретном чатике. Надеюсь, смогу узнать и скорректировать свою точку зрения.

Нельзя все решения рассматривать одинаково, вне зависимости от того, где они приняты. Нужен индивидуальный подход. Слышали, наверное, такой вопрос: "А если все будут с крыши прыгать, ты тоже прыгнешь?", так вот, всё зависит от нюансов. Даже прыжок с крыши может быть во спасение, если здание в огне, а внизу пожарный батут.

Когда модераторы обходят тревоги - нужно объявлять новые выборы.

---

> Работать на благо сообщества вы можете и без статуса модератора. С вашей репутацией у вас уже и так доступны многие инструменты модератора. Так зачем вы действительно решили стать модератором?

Ну, 25К у меня ещё нет, а стало быть ромб уже позволит больше. Ну и довольно часто приходится ставить тревоги типа "добавьте [статус-завершено]", от этого можно будет избавиться и ставить красные метки самостоятельно. Хочешь красную метку - спроси меня как! Время от времени возникают ситуации, когда нехватка информации по сайту не позволяет рассмотреть картину в целом, это приводит к ошибочному пониманию и, как следствие, предложению каких-то ненужных деталей. Будучи модератором можно будет предлагать идеи для улучшения сайта более взвешенно. От этого выиграют все.

---

> В комментариях под одним из вопросов/ответов разгорается конфликт участников, оба апеллируют к техническим деталям.
>
> Вы не являетесь специалистом по метке обсуждаемого вопроса и не понимаете, кто из них прав. И других модераторов онлайн нету.
>
> Какие действия вы предпримете в данной ситуации?

Комментарии под сообщением переносим в чат, технические детали не должны пропасть бесследно. А в чате авось кто и иззабугорья сможет придти и забанить :) Про бан, конечно же, шутка, хоть мы были свидетелями и таких историй. Главное, чтобы владение техническими деталями не перешло в членовредительство, пока переходов на личности нет, общение в чате по техническим нюансам может только приветствоваться. К тому же переписку чата под сообщением можно попробовать перенести в соответствующий тематический чат, где могут быть и другие, знающие обсуждаемую технологию, участники. Т.е. дальше уже модераторы не нужны. Другое дело, что руСО-чаты ещё недостаточно развиты и кажется, как будто, какая-то сила противится их развитию. Это надо исправлять. Хотелось бы, чтобы люди, отвечающие на вопросы на сайте, так же посещали и тематические чат-комнаты на регулярной основе. Тогда сложится более дружное комъюнити.

---

> Назовите 4 главных качества, которыми, на ваш взгляд, должен обладать модератор Stack Overflow на русском.

Уважение к другим участникам. Общительность. Отзывчивость. Ромб.

---

> Чем для Вас является блокировка (бан) участника? В каких случаях, на Ваш взгляд, необходимо прибегать к этим мерам безоговорочно? Считаете ли Вы, что перед принятием такого решения этот вопрос необходимо вынести на обсуждение с сообществом? Или, на Ваш взгляд, это прерогатива сугубо модераторов?

Некоторые точки зрения я уже озвучил в ответах выше. По тому, что ещё не сказал: не думаю, что стоит выносить голосование по бану на Мету. Всё-таки, выбирая кого-то на модераторскую должность люди доверяет ему принятие тех или иных решений, и блокировка - одно из таких решений, как мне кажется. Бан - это всё же возможность отдохнуть. Забаненный отдыхает от написания постов (от которых у него уже глаза покраснели), модераторы - от забаненного. Но иногда нужно и работать (писать посты), поэтому бан не вечен. В целом, read-only доступ это то, чего хватает большинству пользователей, зашёл в гугл - получил ссылку на SO. Аккаунт не нужен. Ну а если чего-то не удалось найти, забаненного участника ничто не остановит от создания нового аккаунта, хотя это уже и идёт против правил сайта.

---

> Что, по-вашему, представляет собой "вредоносный шум"? И как с ним бороться (надо ли?!)?

Любая информация, скрывающая суть - есть шум. Можно рассказать красивую и долгую историю и получить плюсов, но не стоит забывать в таких случаях добавлять в начало TL;DR. Использование Stack Overflow уже позволяет бороться с вредоносным шумом. Хотя всё равно ещё существует множество специфических проблем, которые быстрее удаётся разрешить на тематических форумах, нежели сайтах Stack Exchange.

Comment: Не рассматривал данного кандидата всерьёз из-за чрезмерно шутливого выдвижения (прямо отрывает лавры у лучезарного), однако ответы весьма хорошие, видна и глубина, проработанность мыслей и позиция по многим вопросам мне импонирует. Я думаю, что я однозначно буду голосовать за этого кандидата и рекомендую остальным избирателям присмотреться повнимательнее.

Comment: Т.е. даже если другой модератор не прав, но не хочет в этом признаваться, то лучше всё оставить как есть, потому что «честь мундира»?

Comment: @ixSci зависит от очевидности неправоты. Элементарный случай - орфографическая ошибка, тут можно править сразу. В более неочевидных ситуациях - надо понять другого человека, прежде чем считать его неправым. Иначе это будет какое-то перетягивание каната, результатом которого будет только разрыв этого каната. Поэтому и нужно более взвешенное решение нескольких человек.

Comment: Но Вы же сами пишете, что если к консенсусу прийти не удаётся, то лучше отступить, чтобы не выносить сор из избы (я перефразировал, но вроде смысл не исказил). Я об этом.

Comment: @ixSci вероятно, я слишком широко интерпретировал "и т.д." из того вопроса, поэтому и такой ответ. Если было всего лишь закрытие/удаление, то при наличии у меня ответа - я, скорее всего, переоткрою/восстановлю. Но перед этим вполне может потребоваться правка вопроса, и предыдущий модератор по сути сделал первый и наиболее простой шаг (закрыл/удалил), например, из-за нехватки времени. Т.о., дальнейшее открытие/восстановление после правки вполне можно рассмотреть не как противоположное решение, а скорее эволюционное, не идущее вразрез с действиями первого модератора. Нет сора, нечего и выносить.

Comment: На выборы никогда не ходил, но в этот раз точно пойду. Кандидат от народа! :D

Comment: [tag:продано] (¬‿¬ )

Comment: _"факт объединения учёток"_ - клонов удаляют, а не объединяют.

Comment: @Qwertiy скажите это КМу

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, модераторы удаляют учётки клонов. КМ объединяет только случайно созданных клонов, а не тех, которые использовались для накрутки.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну, допустим, есть два примерно одинаковых аккаунта, постящих вопросы/ответы и взаимно голосующие. Кто из них клон? Тот кто позже зарегистрировался или у кого меньше постов/репы? Мне кажется, объединение с откатом общих голосов - более правильный путь, чем удаление (и как следствие, обезличивание всех действий) одной из учёток. Почему половина постов должна быть обезличена, если авторство можно сохранить?

Answer (score 6):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[@vp_arth](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/176064/vp-arth)

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создаёт большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

Если комментарии этого участника нарушают правила, - удалю их и инициирую алгоритм блокировки(Предупреждение, бан при рецидиве).
Если же сигналы тревоги ложные - я бы отправил сообщение, объясняющее ситуацию автору тревог. За злостное злоупотребление флагами также не исключено наказание.

Главное ведь, не наказать провинившихся, а остановить текущее и не допустить повторное правонарушение.

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

Я не уверен, но скорее всего у модераторов есть место(чат) для обсуждения подобных ситуаций. Я поговорю с этим модератором и в результате этой беседы либо он обоснует свои действия, либо я смогу убедить его их откатить.

---

> Важны ли для вас лично «[Нормы поведения](/conduct)», придерживаетесь ли вы их сами? Считаете ли вы нужным / важным дружелюбное отношение участников друг к другу? Как вы будете бороться с участниками, ведущими себя агрессивно?

Навязывание каких бы то ни было норм поведения - всегда плохая идея. Однако, CoC и be-nice настолько абстрактны и обобщены, что скорее всего я их придерживался даже до того как они появились. Дружелюбное отношение, разумеется важно, но не из-под палки. Лидеры сообщества(КМ, модераторы, активные высокорепы) должны обращать внимание на причины отсутствия дружелюбия, в первую очередь, и пытаться разобраться с ними.

С другой стороны, немотивированную агрессию в адрес других участников нужно пресекать.

Подобной агрессией я считаю реплики вроде "С этим кодом тебе прямая дорога на говнокод.ру!", "Тебя что, в гугле забанили?", оскорбления и т.п.

---

> Что вы будете делать, если обнаружите, что без публикации личной информации участников многие ваши решения выглядят в совершенно другом свете, а опубликовать вы её не можете из-за ограничений мод соглашения.

Это надуманная ситуация. Если участник нарушил правила - он их нарушил. Если сообщество не в состоянии увидеть само нарушение равно как и его последствия - это скорее всего не стоит времени, потраченного на разбирательство.
Если после деперсонализации правонарушения оно перестаёт им быть - значит его и не было.

Если участник, например, оскорбил меня лично в личной переписке, которую я не могу обнародовать - это относится ко мне, а не к сообществу.

---

> Предположим, что участники на Mете с большим перевесом наголосовали за решение, с которым вы категорически несогласны (вырезание спасибо, запрет или разрешение домашней работы, запрет сарказма, you name it). Будете ли вы, как модератор, активно претворять его в жизнь, или постараетесь обойти соответствующие тревоги стороной?

Думаю, что буду иметь в виду мнение сообщества по этому поводу при обработке таких тревог. Голову, однако, тоже отключать не нужно. Обязательно стоит уведомить "нарушителя" в том, что существует вот такое решение сообщества. В общем, руководствоваться принципом не навреди.

> Будете ли вы действовать иначе, если решение было принято не на локальной мете, а на английской MSE? А в случае, если решение принято не участниками, а администрацией сети SE?
>   Да, я могу действовать иначе, если не буду знать о существовании такого решения. Если же решение принято администрацией - на это решение должна быть публичная ссылка. Сложно действовать, если невозможно аргументировать свои действия.
>
> Что вы будете делать, если обнаружите, что остальные модераторы обходят стороной соответствующие тревоги, и они начинают накапливаться?

Если я обнаруживаю X, я начинаю разговаривать с теми, от кого этот X зависит. На мой взгляд - это очевидная модель поведения, разве существует другая?

---

> Работать на благо сообщества вы можете и без статуса модератора. С вашей репутацией у вас уже и так доступны многие инструменты модератора. Так зачем вы действительно решили стать модератором?

Почему решил? Потому что у меня появилась кнопка "Выдвинуть свою кандидатуру".
Зачем это нужно мне? Чтобы иметь возможность принимать участие в обсуждениях, которые модераторы не имеют права публиковать.

---

> В комментариях под одним из вопросов/ответов разгорается конфликт участников, оба апеллируют к техническим деталям.
>   Вы не являетесь специалистом по метке обсуждаемого вопроса и не понимаете, кто из них прав. И других модераторов онлайн нету.
>   Какие действия вы предпримете в данной ситуации?

Перенесу этот конфликт в чат, и если явных нарушений правил нет, пусть говорят.

---

> Назовите 4 главных качества, которыми, на ваш взгляд, должен обладать модератор Stack Overflow на русском.

Модератору должна быть небезразлична судьба сообщества.

Сдержанность. Способность отложить своё решение, чтобы не принимать его в "состоянии аффекта".

Беспристрастность. Модератор, принимая решение, должен уметь отложить своё личное мнение в сторону.

Грамотность.

---

> Чем для Вас является блокировка (бан) участника? В каких случаях, на Ваш взгляд, необходимо прибегать к этим мерам безоговорочно? Считаете ли Вы, что перед принятием такого решения этот вопрос необходимо вынести на обсуждение с сообществом? Или, на Ваш взгляд, это прерогатива сугубо модераторов?

Бан - это страшное наказание, отлучение от сообщества на какой-то срок.
В случаях игнорирования предупреждений, повторного явного нарушения правил.
Принимать решение должны избранные модераторы. Однако, по желанию сообщества и с разрешения забаненного можно и нужно обсудить с сообществом причины блокировки.

Открытость - наше всё.

---

> Что, по-вашему, представляет собой "вредоносный шум"? И как с ним бороться (надо ли?!)?

Я не уверен, что понимаю этот термин, если речь о сайте.
Флуд/спам в вопросах и ответах?

Если речь о чате - то вредоносный шум - это то, за что дали *416*. С этим надо бороться в чате. Аккаунт на сайте из-за этого страдать не должен.

---

> Что вы думаете по поводу критики администрации и модераторов? Можно ли критиковать их решения и ошибки? Что если высказывание кажется ошибочным или даже ложным? Как отличить критику (возможно неумелую или недостаточно аргументированную) от клеветы? А если критика в основе своей объективна, но плохо сформулирована и может вызвать неоднозначную трактовку?

Оскорбления администрации, модераторов и других участников нужно удалять, без вопросов. Это не критика.
Деструктивную критику("Какого лешего у пользователей нет никаких прав?", "Администрация не может обеспечить мир во всём мире!") тоже можно удалять. Автору этой критики можно порекомендовать повторить попытку в более конструктивном ключе.

Обвинения, в чём бы то ни было - это не критика, это обвинения.
Нужно понять в чём цель таких обвинений.. Впрочем, см. предыдущий пункт.

Конструктивная критика - явление хорошее. Это повод для разговора. Желательно этот разговор фиксировать постом на Мете, а не в чате или комментариях к другим постам.

---

> Часть участников сформировала своего рода сопротивление и общается на неприемлемые для администрации (и будущего вас в том числе) темы в стороннем чате. Темы эти зачастую неразрешимые из-за противоречия пользовательских ожиданий и политики компании. Будете ли вы представителем народа, аккуратно проводящим реформы, или будете блюсти незыблемость правил? Первое поднимет вашу репутацию в народе, но войдёт в коренное противоречие с вашими обязанностями и духом модераторства. Второе позволит спокойно заниматься прямыми обязанностями, но, возможно, осложнит вам жизнь в отдалённом будущем, когда на почве клубка противоречий вскроется очередная драма.

Чувствуется вопрос от @Arhad. С вариантами ответов. Ок, кто там электорат? Народ? Ну тогда я выбираю первый вариант.
Не нужно загонять отвечающих в рамки двух альтернатив, да ещё и с толкованиями этих альтернатив.

Моя позиция по поводу решения проблемы с SOпротивлением известна: необходим [открытый диалог](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7567/176064).

Comment: А можете дать определение, что это такое -- *"сообщество"*? (естественно, в вашем понимании)

Comment: @avp, Сообщество это множество(Set) людей, объединенные общими интересами, делами. В контесте ruSO - это активная часть участников проекта; те участники, которым небезразлично, как проект будет выглядеть через год.

Comment: Можно ли сказать, что это люди, которые "тусуются" в Мете и чате "Генерал Дис Куссий"? (поскольку про позицию остальных, даже активно отвечающих, ничего сказать нельзя)

Comment: @vp_arth "В контесте ruSO - это активная часть участников проекта" - таких участников можно по пальцам пересчитать. Думаете, они являют собой всё сообщество при обсуждении?

Comment: @Suvitruf, вопрос был про "моё понимание". А в моём понимании, если участнику безразлично, что будет с проектом, он не является частью сообщества. И да, пальцев у вас не хватит.

Answer (score -4):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Doox911](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/312578/doox911)

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создаёт большое количество
>   ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые
>   впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

Рассмотреть тревоги, если ситуация сложная, узнать мнение других на подобные вещи. Перед законом/правилами все равны. Ввиду того, что я не был никогда модератором, могу предположить, что в целях профилактики и дать возможность остыть есть кнопка — БАН.

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и
>   т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и
>   т. д.?

Сначала дискуссия, возможно после неё кто-то из нас поменяет свою позицию. В случае, когда консенсус не найден, то сообщество. И после этого приму решение.

> Важны ли для вас лично «Нормы поведения», придерживаетесь ли вы их
>   сами? Считаете ли вы нужным / важным дружелюбное отношение участников
>   друг к другу? Как вы будете бороться с участниками, ведущими себя
>   агрессивно?

Да важны. Да придерживаюсь. Мой жизненный прицип — относись к людям так, как хотел бы ты, чтобы относились к тебе. А я уважаю себя и люблю когда со мной уважительно общаются. Всегда, сначала мирное урегулирование конфликта, так как эмоциональную нагрузку текста мы все воспринимаем по разному.

> Что вы будете делать, если обнаружите, что без публикации личной
>   информации участников многие ваши решения выглядят в совершенно другом
>   свете, а опубликовать вы её не можете из-за ограничений мод
>   соглашения.

Не могу дать развёрнутый ответ по данной проблеме, так как не могу представить такую ситуацию.

> Предположим, что участники на Mете с большим перевесом наголосовали за
>   решение, с которым вы категорически несогласны (вырезание спасибо,
>   запрет или разрешение домашней работы, запрет сарказма, you name it).
>   Будете ли вы, как модератор, активно претворять его в жизнь, или
>   постараетесь обойти соответствующие тревоги стороной?
>
> Будете ли вы действовать иначе, если решение было принято не на
>   локальной мете, а на английской MSE? А в случае, если решение принято
>   не участниками, а администрацией сети SE?
>
> Что вы будете делать, если обнаружите, что остальные модераторы
>   обходят стороной соответствующие тревоги, и они начинают
>   накапливаться?

Скажу честно, если противоречия критичны для меня — сложу полномочия. В остальных случаях, решение принято большинством — значит так тому и быть.

> Работать на благо сообщества вы можете и без статуса модератора. С
>   вашей репутацией у вас уже и так доступны многие инструменты
>   модератора. Так зачем вы действительно решили стать модератором?

Возможность отстаивать мнение меньшинства.

> В комментариях под одним из вопросов/ответов разгорается конфликт
>   участников, оба апеллируют к техническим деталям.
>
> Вы не являетесь специалистом по метке обсуждаемого вопроса и не
>   понимаете, кто из них прав. И других модераторов онлайн нету.
>
> Какие действия вы предпримете в данной ситуации?

Конструктивный спор без оскорблений - только приветствуется. В случае неуважительного отношения друг к другу, скорее всего, дам возможность остыть.

> Назовите 4 главных качества, которыми, на ваш взгляд, должен обладать
>   модератор Stack Overflow на русском.

Честность перед самим собой, трезвый взгляд, доброта, общительность.

> Чем для Вас является блокировка (бан) участника? В каких случаях, на
>   Ваш взгляд, необходимо прибегать к этим мерам безоговорочно? Считаете
>   ли Вы, что перед принятием такого решения этот вопрос необходимо
>   вынести на обсуждение с сообществом? Или, на Ваш взгляд, это
>   прерогатива сугубо модераторов?

Вопрос в вопросе и вопросом погоняет. Бан — крайняя мера. Тут нельзя дать однозначный ответ. Каждая ситуация уникальна.

> Что, по-вашему, представляет собой "вредоносный шум"? И как с ним
>   бороться (надо ли?!)?

Для меня это очень сложный вопрос.

Comment: У тебя ответы один другому противоречат...

Comment: Является ли русский язык для вас родным?

Comment: @AK к сожалению, грамотность хромает.

Comment: @AK, это же не обязательное условие, чтобы быть модератором.

Comment: @mymedia Просто подумал о том, отчего грамотность может хромать.